how to remove fixed (top) sash from aluminum single hung
I have an aluminum, single hung, double pane window from around 1986. I want to replace the glass in both panes. Removing the bottom (sliding) pane was easy - it tilts in after and then the entire sash can be removed. But I can't figure out how to get the top (fixed) pane out. There were 2 screws on the outside bottom edge of the top pane. I figured after removing them the top pane would slide out. There are no screws on the inside except to hold the tensioner mechanism for the bottom sash. I was able to remove a plastic strip from inside top edge and can see the glass. So it appears that that top pane does not have a sash frame around it like the bottom pane. I don't see any indication that side pieces around that top pane are removable while the window is in place. My thought is that the aluminum piece on the bottom of the top pane should come out by itself and then I should be able to get the glass out. But I tried coaxing it as much as I dare with a pry bar and hammer. It won't budge. What am I missing?

A photo would be very useful here.

IMO replacing the glass in that old window unit is worth neither the effort nor the expense. Bust out the top pane, grind/cut out all the metal except for what is plastered and/or stucco-ed in, and insert a new "retro-fit" window with an external flange that covers the old exterior framework. Use whatever method is appropriate to trim up the interior. This will be quicker and easier and cheaper than the endeavor you propose.
